# Is torus convex?

Tags: geometric-topology, convex-geometry

Since a torus is Cartesian product of two circles, while circle is a convex object, and Cartesian product of two convex objects is still convex, can I conclude that the donut is a convex object? But torus has a hole in it, so it can’t be convex?

After being corrected, I think it’s the disk not the circle, so the obvious hole in the torus will be filled with a plane, and the donut will be filled in, but the resulting wheel like object still don’t feel like a convex object to me

Comment: A circle is not convex. You may be confusing it with a disk.

Comment: Ah... right right, that’s why there is hole in torus. Even with two disk cross product, the wheel like shape still don’t feel convex to me... basically fill the holes of the Torus

Comment: The product of two disks has no hole in it, indeed it's homeomorphic to a (solid, 4 dimensional) cube

Comment: Ah... right right, the middle part need to filled with infinite many disks :( i was thinking more of a union of a disk with  circle product disk

Comment: No worries! These are all easy mistakes to make. Building geometric intuition is hard, especially for 4-dimensional objects like the product of disks.